# Laravel 5 - Eloquent: easier way to filter a many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship between Lists and Users.
This is the List Model:

```
class ListModel extends Model
{
  protected $table = "lists";

  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'list_user', 'list_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
  }

}
```

This is the User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function lists()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ListModel');
    }
}
```

In a list page, I need to get all the lists belonging to the logged user. The only solution I found is this one:

```
$user = \Auth::user()->id;
$all_lists = ListModel::whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user) {
   $query->where('user_id', $user);
})->active()->get();
```

is there any simpler way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Found this useful https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-eager-load-a-relation-on-authuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lists() relationship is not defined correctly. The inverse of belongsToMany is still belongsToMany (hasMany's inverse is belongsTo):

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function lists()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ListModel', 'list_user', 'user_id', 'list_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Then you can get the lists like this:

```
$user = \Auth::user();

$all_lists = $user->lists()->active()->get()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems much cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

Since current user is already loaded, you can use [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) to load lists for the user:

```
auth()->user()->load('lists');
```

Comment: @Dani this code can't return a list of users. It seems you modified the code. Please show me exact code you're using now.

Comment: I've just tested this exact code and it works perfectly for many-to-many relationship.

Comment: $lists = auth()->user()->load('lists');
and dd($lists) returns the users. However I solved it with devk answer :)

Comment: @Dani so problem wasn't in the `load()` but in the wrongly defined relation. So code from your question doesn't work either then.